# Change colour of specific values in table in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a table in PowerPoint, that is generated from a macro code using VBA. I want to change the colour of the negative numbers to red, and the colour of the positive ones to green(the values that need to change their colour are in the third column). The code that generates the table and puts all numbers into the exact rows and columns is the following:

```
Sub RangeTransferToTable102()
 '
 ' Copy each data cell in Excel range to the PowerPoint Slide 46 Shape 102 Table
 '
 Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
 Dim rng As Excel.Range
 Dim frmt As Variant
 '
 ' Set oPPP to PowerPoint by creating a new instance of PowerPoint.
 ' If PowerPoint is already open, you would instead use the GetObject
 ' method instead.
 '
 Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
 '
 ' Set PowerPoint to be Visible.
 '
pptApp.Visible = msoTrue
 pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide310").Select
 pptApp.Activate
 Worksheets("Switch_CS").Activate
 Set rng = Range("GR2:GV11")

 For rw = 1 To 10
 For cl = 1 To 5
 Data = rng.Cells(rw, cl).Value

 If Not (IsEmpty(rng.Cells(rw, cl))) Then
 If IsNumeric(rng.Cells(rw, cl)) Then 'Convert numeric value to text using number format
 frmt = rng.Cells(rw, cl).NumberFormat
 Data = WorksheetFunction.Text(rng.Cells(rw, cl).Value, frmt)
 End If
 Else
 Data = rng.Cells(rw, cl).Value
 End If
 With pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide310").Shapes("Table 102").table.cell(rw + 1, cl)
 .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Delete
 .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Data
 End With
 Next cl
 Next rw

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub RangeTransferToTable102()
 '
 ' Copy each data cell in Excel range to the PowerPoint Slide 46 Shape 102 Table
 '
 Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
 Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
 Dim rng As Excel.Range
 Dim frmt As Variant
 '
 ' Set oPPP to PowerPoint by creating a new instance of PowerPoint.
 ' If PowerPoint is already open, you would instead use the GetObject
 ' method instead.
 '
 Set pptApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
 '
 ' Set PowerPoint to be Visible.
 '
 pptApp.Visible = msoTrue
 pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide310").Select
 pptApp.Activate
 Worksheets("Switch_CS").Activate
 Set rng = Range("GR2:GV11")

 For rw = 1 To 10
 For cl = 1 To 5
 Data = rng.Cells(rw, cl).Value

 If Not (IsEmpty(rng.Cells(rw, cl))) Then
 If IsNumeric(rng.Cells(rw, cl)) Then 'Convert numeric value to text using number format

 If rng.Cells(rw, cl).value >= 0 Then
 rng.Cells(rw, cl).Font.Color = -11489280
 Else
 rng.Cells(rw, cl).Font.Color = -16776961
 End If

 frmt = rng.Cells(rw, cl).NumberFormat
 Data = WorksheetFunction.Text(rng.Cells(rw, cl).Value, frmt)
 End If
 Else
 Data = rng.Cells(rw, cl).Value
 End If
 With pptApp.ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide310").Shapes("Table 102").table.cell(rw + 1, cl)
 .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Delete
 .Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Data
 End With
 Next cl
 Next rw

 End Sub
```

Comment: It does not work - the code works, but the colour of the cells does not change at all in power point. Thank you!